# In Python (Pandas/Numpy), How to subset a df using a condition and a specific chunk size?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, subset

I have a df

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5, 2, 0], [2, 4, 4, 0], [3, 3, 1, 1], [4, 2, 2, 0], [5, 1, 4, 0], [2, 4, 4, 0], [3, 3, 1, 1], [4, 2, 2, 0], [5, 1, 4, 0]],
                 columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

I want to be able to subset the dataframe according to the following rules: Select the rows which the column 'D' value is 1 and also include the two above them (Chunk Size = 3).

If I apply the rule in the df example, the output should be:

```
   A  B  C  D
1  1  5  2  0
2  2  4  4  0
3  3  3  1  1
5  5  1  4  0
6  2  4  4  0
7  3  3  1  1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work with any `chunk` size:

```
>>> chunk, mask = 3, A['D'] == 1
>>> mask -= mask.shift(-chunk).fillna(0)
>>> A[mask[::-1].cumsum() > 0]
   A  B  C  D
1  1  5  2  0
2  2  4  4  0
3  3  3  1  1
5  5  1  4  0
6  2  4  4  0
7  3  3  1  1
```

Comment: Thx. Why do I get this c:\users\hernan\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:1706: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
  "DataFrame index.", UserWarning)
Does it matter?

Comment: @hernanavella you can do `A[mask[::-1].cumsum()[::-1] > 0]` if you do not want to see the warning, but that warning is totally fine in here.

Comment: @behzad.nouri Any chance you could explain why that small change removes the warning?  I'm getting that warning and having a hard time understanding why.

Comment: @GregoryArenius without adding the `[::-1]` at the end, index of `mask[::-1].cumsum() > 0` does not align with the dataframe. the warning basically says that pandas will do `reindex` to align the indices. see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#vectorized-operations-and-label-alignment-with-series) for some examples of alignment.